# PARTIALLY SOLVED - React code generating ESlint error no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

*Scroll to bottom for most of a solution* 
I'm leaving this posted, just in case someone else has this same problem later.

I'm following a beginner's tutorial (from Wes Bos) to learn React, and I've triple-checked that my code is the same as in the tutorial, but for whatever reason it is triggering an ESlint error (even though, supposedly ESlint isn't even installed in my VS Code).

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { formatPrice } from "../helpers";

class Order extends React.Component {
    renderOrder = key => {
        const fish = this.props.fishes[key];
        const count = this.props.order[key];
        const isAvailable = fish.status === 'available';
        // /*eslint-disable */
        if(!isAvailable) {
            <li>
                Sorry {fish ? fish.name : 'fish'} is no longer available
            </li>
        }
        return (
            <li>
                {count} lbs of {fish.name}
                {formatPrice(count * fish.price)}
            </li>
        );
        // /*eslint-endisable */
    };
    render() {
        const orderIds = Object.keys(this.props.order);
        const total = orderIds.reduce((prevTotal,key) => {
            const fish = this.props.fishes[key];
            const count = this.props.order[key];
            const isAvailable = fish && fish.status === 'available';
            if(isAvailable) {
                return prevTotal + (count * fish.price);
            }
            return prevTotal;
        }, 0);
        return (
            <div className="order-wrap">
                <h2>Order</h2>
                    <ul>
                        {orderIds.map(this.renderOrder)}
                    </ul>
                <div className="total">
                    Total:
                    <strong>{formatPrice(total)}</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Order;
```

The error I'm getting is:

./src/components/Order.js
  Line 10:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Note: Line 10 is the start of my if function

I tried googling the error, but I guess I'm too much of a beginner to understand what I found here:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions

I was able to get this to run (not error, although the if function doesn't seem to work) by using the /*eslint-disable */ /*eslint-endisable */ around the if function, but I'd still like to know:
1. Why is this error occurring?
2. Why is an ESlint error being triggered when I had previously disabled and then uninstalled ESlint from VS code?

Also tried cleaning up the code a little to this, but still doesn't work:

```
// /*eslint-disable */
        if (!isAvailable) {
            <li>Sorry {fish ? fish.name : 'fish'} is no longer available</li>;
        }
        // /*eslint-endisable */
        return (
            <li>
                {count} lbs {fish.name}
                {formatPrice(count * fish.price)}
            </li>
        );
```

And, if I'd just watched the tutorial for 30 more seconds, I would have found out the answer to why the IF function doesn't work, but I was stumped by the ESLint error that I got that did not happen in the tutorial video.  I still don't know why I'm getting ESLint errors, since I don't have it installed, let alone enabled.

Correct code requires a return:

```
renderOrder = key => {
        const fish = this.props.fishes[key];
        const count = this.props.order[key];
        const isAvailable = fish.status === 'available';
        if (!isAvailable) {
// added return below
            return <li>Sorry {fish ? fish.name : 'fish'} is no longer available</li>;
        }
        return (
            <li>
                {count} lbs {fish.name}
                {formatPrice(count * fish.price)}
            </li>
        );
    };
```

Comment: since you don't `return` this expression it's just executed and forgotten immediately

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything in that conditional. You're saying, "If this is true, then this is also true" and your linter is trying to tell you that you probably wanted to do something more than just stating a thing. If you set the list item to a variable and use it elsewhere, the linter should move on.

Edit to go with OP's edit: Likely the reason you're getting ESLinter errors is because the tutorial package you installed came with it and it's own .eslintrc file for rules.

Comment: Thank you; I think that's sort of the case here, and I was able to figure out that I had a few global files present (package-lock.json and node_modules) that once I deleted those and the lower level ones and re-ran my npm install, it seemed to fix some of these weird issues.